# Writing to log files/database files - avoid data corruption due to power loss

Tags: logging, corruption, file-writing

What is proper way of writing to file if we expect possible power failure? I guess common approach is to rename old file, then write to new one, but what if power disruption will occur during file rename operation and it won't get flushed? Is there better way to completely reduce risk of previous file version loss?

Comment: The rename operation is atomic at the filesystem level (it just changes a directory entry; no data is copied). If such an operation is somehow corrupt then there is absolutely nothing to do about it. (Technically the pending operation/data and result can be logged-ahead or audited, which is how databases can remain ACID even in [most] hardware failure conditions).. If power failure is expected, consider using an UPS.